# memory leak discovered MKMapView

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, mkmapview

I have `NSAutoreleasePool` leaked object on a `MKMapView`. should I be concerned about this? I can't seem to get rid of it. I also noticed that the same leak occurs in apple's CurrentAddress sample code app
[link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it depends from Apple's library do not be worried about it (plus it is just 32 byte : D)